# CuratorTransaction KeeperErrorCode = NoNode

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm trying to write data to ZooKeeper using transaction in the Apache Curator library in Java.

Here's my code:

```
private CuratorFramework client;
...
private void writeToZK() {
    String nodePath = "/path/to/node";
    client.inTransaction().create().forPath(nodePath).and().commit(); // problem
}
```

(I'm using curator v2.9.0)

This throws:

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.multiInternal(ZooKeeper.java:949)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.multi(ZooKeeper.java:915)
```

I dug into ZooKeeper.multiInternal(), it got zookeeper response containing

```
OpResult: err = -101, type = -1.
```

If I replace the "// problem" line with this, it works:

```
client.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().forPath(nodePath); // runs with no problem
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you're not using transactions, Curator's standard create() DSL has the creatingParentsIfNeeded() option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In zookeeper every node are defined with a path. Please have a look to the documentation: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperOver.html
They are organised like a standard file system. Which mean you cannot create > "/path/to/node" if "/path/to" does not exist.
The solution you propose is correct because if the parent of your node does not exist it will be automatically created by zookeeper.

Comment: Got it, so basically CuratorTransaction doesn't handle parent nodes gracefully. I created the parent node with a separate create(), and that works. Thanks!

Comment: It's not Curator that's the issue. ZooKeeper itself does not support this.